# Issue with tkinter being unable to open a window (Python + tkinter module)

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't understand what the problem is with my code - it has everything i need and should execute fine.

No error is generated so I believe it is a logic error but I don't know how to fix it per say.

Help with this would be much appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def Payment_Computation(self):

 
def Getting_Payment_in_Monthly():


def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some vital parts of an oop program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainApplication():   # create class

    def __init__(self):
        # method code

    def Payment_Computation(self):
        # method code
     
    def Getting_Payment_in_Monthly(self, Amount_Loan, mon_rate_interest, no_of_yrs):
        # method code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApplication()    # Instantiate class
```

You need to place the code in a class. You then need to instantiate the class as exemplified above.

Read more about oop program structure in [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/8172933)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the `__init__()` function. Please check carefully :)